# Having the SVG Icon to submit the input of a search query

Tags: html, css, svg, input, submit

I have a search bar in my website where the user can type a city and with the Enter key they are redirected to the corresponding city page. Next to the input box I have a SVG of a magnifier lens and I want to transform it in a "submit event" for my form, how can I do it?
Below is the relevant part of the code, I'm using HTML, CSS & JS.

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <form action="javascript:redirect()" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search">
            </form>
            <ul class="mylist list-group" id="result"></ul>
            <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 77 77" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             ........
            </svg>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can put the svg element inside a button `<button type="submit" >
<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 77 77">...
</svg>
</button>`

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta! Simple and effective :)